# How to use Javascript variable inside PHP code in Script

Tags: javascript, function, laravel-5, controller

I have public static function with parameter in my controller. I need to use this function inside javascript which is in `for` loop. How can I use JS for loop variable  inside php vairble as array count?

Here is example of code:

```
var passedArray = {!! json_encode($elanlar)!!};
var passedArrayRegion = {!! json_encode($region)!!};

for (var i = 0; i < my_count; i++) {
  console.log('lat: '+passedArray[i]['Coordinatex']+ ' lng: '+passedArray[i]['Coordinatey'] )
  Ldata.info.push({
      "placeName" : passedArray[i]['Column1']+ ' '+{{$my_php_variable[i]['Column2']}}+' '+ passedArrayRegion[passedArray[i]['Column3']]['Column4']
   });
}
```

`i` here is JS variable
{{$my_php_variable[i]['Column2']}}

I have tried so much variants and read so much in forum, but couldn`t fin an answer.
How to use js variable `i` in this condition?

Comment: you can't use javascript variable inside PHP, since the javascript variable only exists once PHP has finished preprocessing the page on the server, and sent it to the browser

Comment: Beside @Bravo already mentioning that it is not possible, since PHP renders the html code which is then sent to the client, where it has no direct connection to the PHP interpreter, you could still get a result from js to the server, by sending another HTTP request from JS (client) to PHP (server), which then again renders new HTML and JS. You could use [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) and then get the results in the request body. But this kinda 'smells bad' and is probably not what you should be doing if you have other opportunities.

Comment: It's true that you can't use the php variable in javascript, but in the javascript, you can use JSON.parse to turn the encoded json into a javascript object. ```var passedArray = `${JSON.parse({!! json_encode($elanlar)!!})}`;```